# C++ why this code doesn't work?

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
for (auto beg = v.begin(); beg != v.end();++beg)
{
    if (beg == v.begin())
        v.push_back(50);
}
```

During run time, it says : "vector iterator not incrementable".

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: That's a pretty clever runtime you have there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this vector iterator not incrementable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779227/why-is-this-vector-iterator-not-incrementable)

Comment: Please provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Also, you probably want `auto&` and a range based loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use vector iterators when using vector<>::push\_back()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879979/how-to-use-vector-iterators-when-using-vectorpush-back)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I doubt `auto &` would for for `v.begin()`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi no, that's *exactly* the time when `auto` really shines for me, when I just want an iterator but really don't care much what type it needs to be.

Comment: @Slava why do you think this *isn't* a minimal, complete, and verifiable example?

Comment: @MarkRansom because type of `v` is not shown for example?

Comment: @Slava obviously the question was answerable without it, so your complaint was pointless.

Comment: @MarkRansom the fact that we assumed what type used there does not make this question good and does not make example [mcve] either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned `std::vector::push_back()` may invalidate your iterator. Possible, but pretty ugly solution could be:

```
for (auto beg = v.begin(); beg != v.end();++beg)
{
    if (beg == v.begin()) {
        v.push_back(50);
        beg = v.begin();
    }
}
```

but your logic seems convoluted, why not push back just before the loop?

Comment: I didn't thought about the code, I just wanted to know why this is an error.

Comment: Answers on SO are not only for you, and that is the reason I asked you to fix your code.

Comment: I think that the reason why push_back() invalidates all iterators is because push_back() change the memory address occupied by the vector, am I right?

Comment: @gigi `push_back` **may** invalidate iterators. And actually in your updated example most probably it would not to. Now you should see why [mcve] is asked. But yes, vector may have to reallocate memory for storage if `capacity()` will be not big enough to hold new data size.

Answer (score 9):

See [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then **all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated**. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

In your example, `beg` is an iterator. It is being invalidated by the push_back, you cannot use it anymore.